# Summing Duplicates Across Sublists in a Nested List

Tags: python, list, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement

I hope my message finds you well. I am seeking your expertise and feedback on a specific issue I have encountered in the `repeat_sum` function within the codebase. The function is designed to compute the sum of integers that are present in two or more sublists within the input list

Here is the current implementation:

```
def repeat_sum(arr):
    arr_comp = []
    arr_sum = []
    arr_sum_final = []
    for i in arr:
        for j in i:
            arr_comp.append(j)
    for i in arr_comp:
        if (arr_comp.count(i)) > 1:
            arr_sum.append(i)
    for i in arr_sum:
        if i not in arr_sum_final:
            arr_sum_final.append(i)
    return sum(arr_sum_final)
```

However, I've identified a case where the function fails to provide the correct result. Specifically, when dealing with a nested list and duplicate elements, the function might return an incorrect value. In this case `[[1], [2], [3, 4, 4], [5]],` the correct result would be `0`, as the only duplicate integer, `4`, is confined within a single sublist.

I believe the issue stems from the function's current approach, which involves flattening the nested list and then identifying duplicates. To address this, I am seeking your guidance on a more robust solution that correctly handles cases like the one mentioned.

Your insights and suggestions on improving the `repeat_sum` function would be highly appreciated. Please feel free to share any comments or alternative approaches to ensure the accuracy and efficiency of the code.

---

some sample inputs and expected outputs

- *input* ==> **[[1, 2, 3],[2, 8, 9],[7, 123, 8]]** *output* ==> **10**
- *input* ==> **[[1, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8, 1]]** *output* ==> **9**
- *input* ==> **[[1], [2], [3, 4, 4, 4], [123456789]]** *output* ==> **0**

---

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def repeat_sum(arr):
    seen = {}
    for subl in arr:
        for v in {*subl}:
            seen[v] = seen.get(v, 0) + 1
    return sum(k for k, v in seen.items() if v > 1)


test_cases = [
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 8, 9], [7, 123, 8]],
    [[1, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8, 1]],
    [[1], [2], [3, 4, 4, 4], [123456789]],
]

for t in test_cases:
    print(t, repeat_sum(t))
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 8, 9], [7, 123, 8]] 10
[[1, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8, 1]] 9
[[1], [2], [3, 4, 4, 4], [123456789]] 0
```

Comment: I don't want to use external libraries. My goal is to delete duplicate elements in sublist using loop and some condition

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine Can you please edit your question and put there some sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Yes, i added it

Comment: please don't using set using loop my goal is not to use existing things. I want to make them. I hope you understand me

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine I don't understand, why don't you want use `set`? You can use `dict.from_keys`, but it's the same thing.

Comment: I want to use for loop and some condition it's possible

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine I've updated the answer.

Comment: You did not understand what I want. I want to use a loop. What I want is the same as my code. Only this line of code `arr_comp.append(j)`. I want not to add duplicate elements.

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine If you don't want to add duplicate elements, then use set.

Comment: I don't want to use set I want to use loop

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine set internally use loop too... I don't understand.

Comment: You made the code complicated and didn't simplify it

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine your limitations and demands sound a bit artificial. "I don't want" is not a rational argument. If you have technical limitation or requirements then please explain. Furthermore - even if the solution provided is not exactly what you need, you should thank the person who spent time on replying to your question.

Comment: @khachik No, on the contrary, mr Andrej Kesely a wonderful and diligent developer. His solutions are wonderful, and I always follow his solutions, but he was not successful in this question of mine.

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine Look, you can "imitate" sets with lists, but that's not what you want - the running time would be n^2 - because you must iterate the lists over and over again (and thats not what you generally want). Set is the data structure you want to use here.

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine his is successful. Your question does not mention any limitations around not using sets and dictionaries and asks for a correct and efficient solution which in this particular case is achieved by using sets/dicts.

Comment: @khachik Yes, I know, but I made some suggestions in my comments

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine *"my goal is not to use existing things"* - Python and English exist...

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine "my goal is not to use existing things" then why you are using lists?

Comment: I see no less sets used in rev. 3 than in [rev 2](/revisions/77626400/2).